# My wifi adapter is not detected by ubuntu 18

Tags: internet, ethernet

When I previously used Ubuntu 16 before getting Ubuntu 18 I had the issue of the computer not detecting my home wifi network.

Upgrading to Ubuntu 18 didn't solve my problem.

When I check the wifi tab in the settings it says No wifi adapter found.

`ifconfig` output:

```
enpos25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,
MULTICAST> mtu 500
ether 00:19:d1:73:0f:53 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0B)
RX errors 0 dropped 0
 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0 dropped overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0.

lo flags=73<Up,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback) 
RX packets 6186 bytes 372631 (372.6 KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 TX packets 6186 bytes 372631 (372.6 KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0.
```

`lpsci -nn | grep net` output:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel corporation 82562V 10/100 Network conection [8086:104c] (rev 02).
```

`iwconfig` output

```
lo no wireless extensions 
enpos25 no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: There may be a hardware switch or BIOS setting that has switched the WiFi off.

Comment: I edited your post to remove much of what I thought wasn't relevant to make it easier to read. If it no longer captures the essence of your problem feel free to roll the edit back. I highly recommend that you review https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and then return to [edit] this post to provide further detail as it's missing critical information necessary to provide an accurate answer. Personally at the very least I'd like to see the output of `sudo lshw -C network; rfkill list` Thank you for helping us help!

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem same with wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

Firstly, you will need to see all your available interfaces:

`ifconfig -a` or `ip link`

The one that starts with `w` is your wireless interface.

Next, you could try to enable it by using:

`sudo ifconfig wlo1 up`   -- change `wlo1` with your network interface name

If you get an error like `Operation not possible due to RF-KILL`, you will need to add the following line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist wmi
```

After that, you enable your wifi interface:

`sudo ifconfig wlo1 up`

Then add the following lines to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlo1
iface wlo1 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid SSID
    wpa-psk PASSWORD
```

Where `wlo1` is the name of my wifi interface and `SSID` is the wifi network name and `PASSWORD` is the wifi pass.

Then you can check if your interface can find networks around you with:

`sudo iwlist wlo1 scan`  -- change `wlo1` with your network interface name

Then you restart the service using:

`sudo service networking restart`

Comment: When i type in sudo iwlist lo in the terminal it says Interface does not support scanning. And i dont see anything that starts with w but i do see the devices lo and enpos25 when typing in ifconfig-a.

Comment: What is the output of `lshw -C network`? It shows your wifi card?

Comment: Description: Ethernet Interface product: 8526V 10 100 Network conection vendor:intel corporation

Comment: It could be a BIOS setting that has switched it off, a hardware switch or rfkill. Have you tried `rfkill list all` to see if it's blocked? More info you can find here https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Its blank i dont see anything

Comment: description: Ethernet Interface product: 82562V 10/100 Network conection vendor intel corporation physical id 19 bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0 logical name enp0s25 version 02 serial 00: 19:d1:73:0f:53 capacity : 100 Mbit/s

Comment: Couldnt type out the rest because of that dumb time limit 